# Resampling Within a Pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, multi-index, hierarchical-data

I have some hierarchical data which bottoms out into time series data which looks something like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'value_a': values_a, 'value_b': values_b},
    index=[states, cities, dates])
df.index.names = ['State', 'City', 'Date']
df

                               value_a  value_b
State   City       Date                        
Georgia Atlanta    2012-01-01        0       10
                   2012-01-02        1       11
                   2012-01-03        2       12
                   2012-01-04        3       13
        Savanna    2012-01-01        4       14
                   2012-01-02        5       15
                   2012-01-03        6       16
                   2012-01-04        7       17
Alabama Mobile     2012-01-01        8       18
                   2012-01-02        9       19
                   2012-01-03       10       20
                   2012-01-04       11       21
        Montgomery 2012-01-01       12       22
                   2012-01-02       13       23
                   2012-01-03       14       24
                   2012-01-04       15       25
```

I'd like to perform time resampling per city, so something like

```
df.resample("2D", how="sum")
```

would output

```
                             value_a  value_b
State   City       Date                        
Georgia Atlanta    2012-01-01        1       21
                   2012-01-03        5       25
        Savanna    2012-01-01        9       29
                   2012-01-03       13       33
Alabama Mobile     2012-01-01       17       37
                   2012-01-03       21       41
        Montgomery 2012-01-01       25       45
                   2012-01-03       29       49
```

as is, `df.resample('2D', how='sum')` gets me

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

Fair enough, but I'd sort of expect this to work:

```
>>> df.swaplevel('Date', 'State').resample('2D', how='sum')
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

at which point I'm really running out of ideas... is there some way stack and unstack might be able to help me?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[`pd.Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/generated/pandas.Grouper.html)
allows you to specify a "groupby instruction for a target object". In
particular, you can use it to group by dates even if `df.index` is not a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2D', level=-1))
```

The `level=-1` tells `pd.Grouper` to look for the dates in the last level of the MultiIndex.
Moreover, you can use this in conjunction with other level values from the index:

```
level_values = df.index.get_level_values
result = (df.groupby([level_values(i) for i in [0,1]]
                      +[pd.Grouper(freq='2D', level=-1)]).sum())
```

It looks a bit awkward, but `using_Grouper` turns out to be much faster than my original
suggestion, `using_reset_index`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT

def using_Grouper(df):
    level_values = df.index.get_level_values
    return (df.groupby([level_values(i) for i in [0,1]]
                       +[pd.Grouper(freq='2D', level=-1)]).sum())

def using_reset_index(df):
    df = df.reset_index(level=[0, 1])
    return df.groupby(['State','City']).resample('2D').sum()

def using_stack(df):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/15813787/190597
    return (df.unstack(level=[0,1])
              .resample('2D').sum()
              .stack(level=[2,1])
              .swaplevel(2,0))

def make_orig():
    values_a = range(16)
    values_b = range(10, 26)
    states = ['Georgia']*8 + ['Alabama']*8
    cities = ['Atlanta']*4 + ['Savanna']*4 + ['Mobile']*4 + ['Montgomery']*4
    dates = pd.DatetimeIndex([DT.date(2012,1,1)+DT.timedelta(days = i) for i in range(4)]*4)
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'value_a': values_a, 'value_b': values_b},
        index = [states, cities, dates])
    df.index.names = ['State', 'City', 'Date']
    return df

def make_df(N):
    dates = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N)
    states = np.arange(50)
    cities = np.arange(10)
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([states, cities, dates], 
                                       names=['State', 'City', 'Date'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(len(index),2)), index=index,
                      columns=['value_a', 'value_b'])
    return df

df = make_orig()
print(using_Grouper(df))
```

yields

```
                               value_a  value_b
State   City       Date                        
Alabama Mobile     2012-01-01       17       37
                   2012-01-03       21       41
        Montgomery 2012-01-01       25       45
                   2012-01-03       29       49
Georgia Atlanta    2012-01-01        1       21
                   2012-01-03        5       25
        Savanna    2012-01-01        9       29
                   2012-01-03       13       33
```

---

Here is a benchmark comparing `using_Grouper`, `using_reset_index`, `using_stack` on a 5000-row DataFrame:

```
In [30]: df = make_df(10)

In [34]: len(df)
Out[34]: 5000

In [32]: %timeit using_Grouper(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.03 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit using_stack(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.3 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit using_reset_index(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 659 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks -- that certainly does the job, but that groupby is forcing us to recompute the relations we've already established in our hierarchical index.  
Is there not a way to do this with the groupings we've already built in our hierarchical index, or are hierarchical indexes just not meant to be used for this sort of thing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not experienced enough with Pandas to say. The above is more of a workaround than a solution. `df.reset_index` can be a slow operation and it would be much nicer if this could be done without it.

Comment: An alternative would be to unstack the State and City columns before resampling, but i doubt if thats more efficient.

Comment: Interestingly, this is more performant than stacking and unstacking:

In [561]: timeit.timeit("from __main__ import df; df.reset_index(level=[0,1]).groupby(['State', 'City']).resample('2D', how='sum')", number=1000)
Out[561]: 7.496185064315796

In [562]: timeit.timeit("from __main__ import df; df.unstack(level=[0,1]).resample('2D', how='sum').stack(level=[2,1]).swaplevel(2,0)", number=1000)
Out[562]: 10.618878841400146

Comment: I think the real answer here is "if you're doing these sorts of calculations, you should be working with a groupby object, not a hierarchical index"

Comment: @unutbu "Sorry, I'm not experienced enough with Pandas to say." Funny to read that, 1000+ answers later...

Comment: @Def_Os: Happily, 1000+ answers later, I can say there is a faster solution -- use `pd.Grouper`.

Comment: @unutbu, I have tried to use your method (my df has a triple index including `'#' (int)`, `'jobid' (string)`, `'datetime' (datetime)` but with a `pd.Grouper(freq='2D')` I obtained an odd resampling, i.e. new df lacks every second day but timeseries still has hourly values. Not sure what I am saying is clear?

Comment: @Andreuccio: Could you construct an example which reproduces the problem? It might be easiest to post it in a new question. I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: @unutbu, I actually did here but forgot to include the link
https://stackoverflow.com/q/44718125/6071128

Answer (score 51):

You need the [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method and provide it with a [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) for each level of your MultiIndex you wish to maintain in the resulting DataFrame. You can then apply an operation of choice.

To resample date or timestamp levels, you need to set the `freq` argument with the frequency of choice — a similar approach using `pd.TimeGrouper()` is deprecated in favour of `pd.Grouper()` with the `freq` argument set.

This should give you the DataFrame you need:

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='State'), 
            pd.Grouper(level='City'), 
            pd.Grouper(level='Date', freq='2D')]
          ).sum()
```

The [Time Series Guide](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling) in the pandas documentation describes `resample()` as:

> ... a time-based groupby, followed by a reduction method on each of its groups.

Hence, using `groupby()` should technically be the same operation as using `.resample()` on a DataFrame with a single index.

The same paragraph points to the [cookbook section on resampling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html#resampling) for more advanced examples, where the '[Grouping using a MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483763/pandas-timegrouper-on-multiindex)' entry is highly relevant for this question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Unlike a lot of convoluted answers to this problem, this is an easy to understand solution that results in easy to read code.

Answer (score 17):

An alternative using stack/unstack

```
df.unstack(level=[0,1]).resample('2D', how='sum').stack(level=[2,1]).swaplevel(2,0)

                               value_a  value_b
State   City       Date
Georgia Atlanta    2012-01-01        1       21
Alabama Mobile     2012-01-01       17       37
        Montgomery 2012-01-01       25       45
Georgia Savanna    2012-01-01        9       29
        Atlanta    2012-01-03        5       25
Alabama Mobile     2012-01-03       21       41
        Montgomery 2012-01-03       29       49
Georgia Savanna    2012-01-03       13       33
```

Notes:

1. No idea about performance comparison
2. Possible pandas bug - stack(level=[2,1]) worked, but stack(level=[1,2]) failed

Comment: I ran into trouble calculating `pct_change` right after this. Similar problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790415/how-to-groupby-multiple-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-in-pct-change-calculation). I ended  up with doing the following: `reset_index, sort_values, groupby, pct_change` (as in the link)

Answer (score 10):

This works:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Date').resample('2D', how='sum'))

                               value_a  value_b
State   City       Date
Alabama Mobile     2012-01-01       17       37
                   2012-01-03       21       41
        Montgomery 2012-01-01       25       45
                   2012-01-03       29       49
Georgia Atlanta    2012-01-01        1       21
                   2012-01-03        5       25
        Savanna    2012-01-01        9       29
                   2012-01-03       13       33
```

If the Date column is strings, then convert to datetime beforehand:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Comment: @jimbasquiat - no, this is very slow.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, was breaking my head for a while, but then I read the documentation of the `.resample` function in the [0.19.2 docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample), and I see there's a new `kwarg` called "level" that you can use to specify a level in a MultiIndex.

Edit: More details in the ["What's New"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/whatsnew.html#other-enhancements) section.

Comment: Doesnt really answer the question about when you need to resample while preserving multiple indexes. In the docs, level kwarg must be a datetime-like parameter and the question was around non-datetime secondary grouping columns

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a few years old, but I had the same problem and came to a simpler solution that requires 1 line:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ts = pd.read_pickle('time_series.pickle')
>>> ts
xxxxxx1  yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy1  2012-07-01     1
                                  2012-07-02    13
                                  2012-07-03     1
                                  2012-07-04     1
                                  2012-07-05    10
                                  2012-07-06     4
                                  2012-07-07    47
                                  2012-07-08     0
                                  2012-07-09     3
                                  2012-07-10    22
                                  2012-07-11     3
                                  2012-07-12     0
                                  2012-07-13    22
                                  2012-07-14     1
                                  2012-07-15     2
                                  2012-07-16     2
                                  2012-07-17     8
                                  2012-07-18     0
                                  2012-07-19     1
                                  2012-07-20    10
                                  2012-07-21     0
                                  2012-07-22     3
                                  2012-07-23     0
                                  2012-07-24    35
                                  2012-07-25     6
                                  2012-07-26     1
                                  2012-07-27     0
                                  2012-07-28     6
                                  2012-07-29    23
                                  2012-07-30     0
                                                ..
xxxxxxN  yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyN  2014-06-02     0
                                  2014-06-03     1
                                  2014-06-04     0
                                  2014-06-05     0
                                  2014-06-06     0
                                  2014-06-07     0
                                  2014-06-08     2
                                  2014-06-09     0
                                  2014-06-10     0
                                  2014-06-11     0
                                  2014-06-12     0
                                  2014-06-13     0
                                  2014-06-14     0
                                  2014-06-15     0
                                  2014-06-16     0
                                  2014-06-17     0
                                  2014-06-18     0
                                  2014-06-19     0
                                  2014-06-20     0
                                  2014-06-21     0
                                  2014-06-22     0
                                  2014-06-23     0
                                  2014-06-24     0
                                  2014-06-25     4
                                  2014-06-26     0
                                  2014-06-27     1
                                  2014-06-28     0
                                  2014-06-29     0
                                  2014-06-30     1
                                  2014-07-01     0
dtype: int64
>>> ts.unstack().T.resample('W', how='sum').T.stack()
xxxxxx1  yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy1  2012-06-25/2012-07-01      1
                                  2012-07-02/2012-07-08     76
                                  2012-07-09/2012-07-15     53
                                  2012-07-16/2012-07-22     24
                                  2012-07-23/2012-07-29     71
                                  2012-07-30/2012-08-05     38
                                  2012-08-06/2012-08-12    258
                                  2012-08-13/2012-08-19    144
                                  2012-08-20/2012-08-26    184
                                  2012-08-27/2012-09-02    323
                                  2012-09-03/2012-09-09    198
                                  2012-09-10/2012-09-16    348
                                  2012-09-17/2012-09-23    404
                                  2012-09-24/2012-09-30    380
                                  2012-10-01/2012-10-07    367
                                  2012-10-08/2012-10-14    163
                                  2012-10-15/2012-10-21    338
                                  2012-10-22/2012-10-28    252
                                  2012-10-29/2012-11-04    197
                                  2012-11-05/2012-11-11    336
                                  2012-11-12/2012-11-18    234
                                  2012-11-19/2012-11-25    143
                                  2012-11-26/2012-12-02    204
                                  2012-12-03/2012-12-09    296
                                  2012-12-10/2012-12-16    146
                                  2012-12-17/2012-12-23     85
                                  2012-12-24/2012-12-30    198
                                  2012-12-31/2013-01-06    214
                                  2013-01-07/2013-01-13    229
                                  2013-01-14/2013-01-20    192
                                                          ...
xxxxxxN  yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyN  2013-12-09/2013-12-15      3
                                  2013-12-16/2013-12-22      0
                                  2013-12-23/2013-12-29      0
                                  2013-12-30/2014-01-05      1
                                  2014-01-06/2014-01-12      3
                                  2014-01-13/2014-01-19      6
                                  2014-01-20/2014-01-26     11
                                  2014-01-27/2014-02-02      0
                                  2014-02-03/2014-02-09      1
                                  2014-02-10/2014-02-16      4
                                  2014-02-17/2014-02-23      3
                                  2014-02-24/2014-03-02      1
                                  2014-03-03/2014-03-09      4
                                  2014-03-10/2014-03-16      0
                                  2014-03-17/2014-03-23      0
                                  2014-03-24/2014-03-30      9
                                  2014-03-31/2014-04-06      1
                                  2014-04-07/2014-04-13      1
                                  2014-04-14/2014-04-20      1
                                  2014-04-21/2014-04-27      2
                                  2014-04-28/2014-05-04      8
                                  2014-05-05/2014-05-11      7
                                  2014-05-12/2014-05-18      5
                                  2014-05-19/2014-05-25      2
                                  2014-05-26/2014-06-01      8
                                  2014-06-02/2014-06-08      3
                                  2014-06-09/2014-06-15      0
                                  2014-06-16/2014-06-22      0
                                  2014-06-23/2014-06-29      5
                                  2014-06-30/2014-07-06      1
dtype: int64
```

`ts.unstack().T.resample('W', how='sum').T.stack()` is all it took! Very easy and seems quite performant. The pickle I'm reading in is 331M, so this is a pretty beefy data structure; the resampling takes just a couple seconds on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: Nice, but this only works if you have a single column.

Comment: This one indeed works nicely if your dates are on level 0 of the multiindex, and is reasonably fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the efficiency of this, but my instinctual way of performing datetime operations on a multi-index was by a kind of manual "split-apply-combine" process using a dictionary comprehension.

Assuming your DataFrame is unindexed. (You can do `.reset_index()` first), this works as follows:

1. Group by the non-date columns
2. Set "Date" as index and resample each chunk
3. Reassemble using `pd.concat`

The final code looks like:

```
pd.concat({g: x.set_index("Date").resample("2D").mean()
                   for g, x in house.groupby(["State", "City"])})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on my own, pretty short and pretty simple too (I will only work with 2 indexes, and you would get the full idea):

**Step 1**: resample the date but that would give you the date without the other index :

```
new=df.reset_index('City').groupby('crime', group_keys=False).resample('2d').sum().pad()
```

That would give you the date and its count

**Step 2**: get the categorical index in the same order as the the date :

```
col=df.reset_index('City').groupby('City', group_keys=False).resample('2D').pad()[['City']]
```

That would give you a new column with the city names and in the same order as the date.

**Step 3**: merge the dataframes together

```
new_df=pd.concat([new, col], axis=1)
```

It's pretty simple, you can make it really shorter tho.