# Pandas TimeGrouper on multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiIndex pandas dataframe, where the first level index is a group and the second level index is time.
What I want to do is, within each group, to resample to daily frequency taking the average of intraday observations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([['A']*72, list(pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')), list(np.random.rand(72))], index = ['Group', 'Time', 'Value']).T,
                  pd.DataFrame([['B']*72, list(pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')), list(np.random.rand(72))], index = ['Group', 'Time', 'Value']).T,
                  pd.DataFrame([['C']*72, list(pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')), list(np.random.rand(72))], index = ['Group', 'Time', 'Value']).T],
                  axis = 0).set_index(['Group', 'Time'])
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
daily_counts = data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D'), level = ['Time']).mean()
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need first cast column to `float` and then use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
data['Value'] = data['Value'].astype(float)
daily_counts = data.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D', level='Time'), 
                             pd.Grouper(level='Group')])['Value'].mean()

print (daily_counts) 
Time        Group
2011-01-01  A        0.548358
            B        0.612878
            C        0.544822
2011-01-02  A        0.529880
            B        0.437062
            C        0.388626
2011-01-03  A        0.563854
            B        0.479299
            C        0.557190
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Another solution:

```
data = data.reset_index(level='Group')
print (data.groupby('Group').resample('D')['Value'].mean())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved my problem.
So I guess the main take-away is that when I want to groupby on a MultiIndex I still need to pass all the index levels as groupers. Is it fair?

Comment: Yes, but maybe is more common use second solution, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-syntax-with-window-and-resample-operations).

Comment: On your second solution, worth highlighting this bug (fixed in pandas 0.19) that might prevent to use kwargs in resample: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13235

Comment: Note that `pd.TimeGrouper()` is deprecated in favour of `pd.Grouper()` with the `freq` argument set.