# Resampling a pandas dataframe with multi-index containing timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, multi-index

apologies from creating what appears to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799162/resampling-within-a-pandas-multiindex). I have a dataframe that is shaped more or less like the one below:

```
df_lenght = 240
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(df_lenght,2), columns=['a','b'] )
df['datetime'] = pd.date_range('23/06/2017', periods=df_lenght, freq='H')

unique_jobs = ['job1','job2','job3',]
job_id = [unique_jobs for i in range (1, int((df_lenght/len(unique_jobs))+1) ,1) ]
df['job_id'] = sorted( [val for sublist in job_id for val in sublist] )

df.set_index(['job_id','datetime'], append=True, inplace=True)
```

`print(df[:5])` returns:

```
                                     a         b
  job_id datetime                               
0 job1   2017-06-23 00:00:00 -0.067011 -0.516382
1 job1   2017-06-23 01:00:00 -0.174199  0.068693
2 job1   2017-06-23 02:00:00 -1.227568 -0.103878
3 job1   2017-06-23 03:00:00 -0.847565 -0.345161
4 job1   2017-06-23 04:00:00  0.028852  3.111738
```

I will need to resample `df['a']` to derive a daily rolling mean, i.e. apply a `.resample('D').mean().rolling(window=2).mean()`.

I have tried two methods:

1 - unstacking and stacking, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15813787/6071128)

```
df.unstack('job_id','datetime').resample('D').mean().rolling(window=2).mean().stack('job_id', 'datetime')
```

this returns an error

2 - using `pd.Grouper`, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15799355/6071128)

```
level_values = df.index.get_level_values
result = df.groupby( [ level_values(i) for i in [0,1] ] + [ pd.Grouper(freq='D', level=2) ] ).mean().rolling(window=2).mean()
```

this does not return an error but it does not seem to resample/group the df appropriately. Result seems to contain hourly data points, rather than daily:

```
print(result[:5])
                            a         b
  job_id datetime                      
0 job1   2017-06-23       NaN       NaN
1 job1   2017-06-23  0.831609  1.348970
2 job1   2017-06-23 -0.560047  1.063316
3 job1   2017-06-23 -0.641936 -0.199189
4 job1   2017-06-23  0.254402 -0.328190
```

Comment: How do you want to handle job_id?

Comment: in the index hierarchy, `job_id` comes before `datetime`, i.e. for each value of `job_id` there will be a set of `datetime` values

Comment: Jobid appears unique, while resampling, how to handle it?

Comment: @Allen I have amended the question to better represent my dataset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let's define a resampler function:

```
def resampler(x):    
    return x.set_index('datetime').resample('D').mean().rolling(window=2).mean()
```

Then, we groupby job_id and apply the resampler function:

```
 df.reset_index(level=2).groupby(level=1).apply(resampler)

Out[657]: 
                          a         b
job_id datetime                      
job1   2017-06-23       NaN       NaN
       2017-06-24  0.053378  0.004727
       2017-06-25  0.265074  0.234081
       2017-06-26  0.192286  0.138148
job2   2017-06-26       NaN       NaN
       2017-06-27 -0.016629 -0.041284
       2017-06-28 -0.028662  0.055399
       2017-06-29  0.113299 -0.204670
job3   2017-06-29       NaN       NaN
       2017-06-30  0.233524 -0.194982
       2017-07-01  0.068839 -0.237573
       2017-07-02 -0.051211 -0.069917
```

Let me know if this is what you are after.

Comment: that does not seem to work for my case. I noticed you suggested to drop the default index (with numerals), but that bit on answer disappeared. Could that be what prevents the groupby to work?

Comment: I realized we can just ignore the default index. When you run the code, does it work on the example data you provided?

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, you wish to group by `job_id` and (daily) `datetime`s, and wish to ignore the first level of the DataFrame index. Therefore, instead of grouping by

```
( [ level_values(i) for i in [0,1] ] + [ pd.Grouper(freq='D', level=2) ] )
```

you'd want to groupby

```
[df.index.get_level_values(1), pd.Grouper(freq='D', level=2)]
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2017)

df_length = 240
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(df_length,2), columns=['a','b'] )
df['datetime'] = pd.date_range('23/06/2017', periods=df_length, freq='H')

unique_jobs = ['job1','job2','job3',]
job_id = [unique_jobs for i in range (1, int((df_length/len(unique_jobs))+1) ,1) ]
df['job_id'] = sorted( [val for sublist in job_id for val in sublist] )

df.set_index(['job_id','datetime'], append=True, inplace=True)

grouped = df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(1), pd.Grouper(freq='D', level=2)])
result = grouped.mean().rolling(window=2).mean()

print(result)
```

yields

```
                          a         b
job_id datetime                      
job1   2017-06-23       NaN       NaN
       2017-06-24 -0.203083  0.176141
       2017-06-25 -0.077083  0.072510
       2017-06-26 -0.237611 -0.493329
job2   2017-06-26 -0.297775 -0.370543
       2017-06-27  0.005124  0.052603
       2017-06-28  0.226142 -0.015584
       2017-06-29 -0.065595  0.210628
job3   2017-06-29 -0.186865  0.347683
       2017-06-30  0.051508  0.029909
       2017-07-01  0.005341  0.075378
       2017-07-02 -0.027131  0.132192
```

Comment: thank you very much, your solution also worked. I have just realised how tricky would be for me to re-arrange all the data manipulation using multi-indexes, thus I will attempt to `slice` the main df into many, i.e. one for each value of `job_id`.
Not quite sure about how to do it, possibly using a dictionary? I'll post a separate question

Comment: @Andreuccio: Vectorized operations such as those provided by NumPy and Pandas perform best when applied to a single large array or NDFrame (rather than multiple calls on smaller arrays or NDFrames). Therefore, for the sake of performance it is usually better to keep one large DataFrame with a MultiIndex rather than a dict of smaller DataFrames. If performance is a priority, you may want to pose a question about how to deal with the MultiIndex...

Comment: I totally get your rationale, but the problem is I am spending days trying to perform the data analysis with multi-index, so I am not really bothered about a couple of minutes more of cpu time!
Have posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725105/sub-select-a-multi-index-pandas-dataframe-to-create-multiple-subsets-using-a-di

Comment: can you please open a chatroom with me?

Comment: Sorry, this is not a good time for me, but if you leave a comment I'll try to get back to you.

Comment: are you available today?