# Sub-select a multi-index pandas dataframe to create multiple subsets (using a dictionary)

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataset similar to the following:

```
df_lenght = 240
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(df_lenght,2), columns=['a','b'] )
df['datetime'] = pd.date_range('23/06/2017', periods=df_lenght, freq='H')
unique_jobs = ['job1','job2','job3',]
job_id = [unique_jobs for i in range (1, int((df_lenght/len(unique_jobs))+1) ,1) ]
df['job_id'] = sorted( [val for sublist in job_id for val in sublist] )
df.set_index(['job_id','datetime'], append=True, inplace=True)
```

`print(df[:5])` returns:

```
                                     a         b
  job_id datetime                               
0 job1   2017-06-23 00:00:00 -0.067011 -0.516382
1 job1   2017-06-23 01:00:00 -0.174199  0.068693
2 job1   2017-06-23 02:00:00 -1.227568 -0.103878
3 job1   2017-06-23 03:00:00 -0.847565 -0.345161
4 job1   2017-06-23 04:00:00  0.028852  3.111738
```

How can I create multiple `dataframes`, one for each value of `job_id`? Can those fed into a dictionary to be easy retrieved?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could unpack a `groupby` object into a dictionary:

```
dfs = {job: df for job, df in df.groupby(level='job_id')}
```

Comment: thanks. How would I go about selecting data using the dictionary then?

Comment: You could simply write dfs['job1'], for example.